# cubic bézier curve issue

Tags: c#, .net, bezier

I am trying to optimize a bezier curve implementation by using the formula used in [this wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves) I have a horribly slow implentation now but at least it should be accurate. Using the following:

```
p0 = (0, 256) //Violet dot
p1 = (70, 223) //Green dot
p2 = (24, 472) //Blue dot
p3 = (255, 256) //Yellow dot
t = 0.5
```

Drawn with my current code below, the point at T = 0.5 is (67.125, 324.625)

[image]

Trying the formula for the X-axis, I do a calculation like this:

```
var x = Math.Pow(1 - t, 3) * p0.X + 3 * Math.Pow(1 - t, 2) * t * p1.X + 3 
        * (1 - t) * Math.Pow(t, 2) * p2.X + Math.Pow(t, 3) + p3.X;
```

But this gives me an X coordinate of 290.375 which is obviously not right. What am I missing here?

Comment: `Math.Pow` is not optimized for low integer powers. You can get a significant speed boost without losing significant precision by calculating the powers manually.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @harold. That was new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duh! Looking at my own question now, I see the obvious. The last bit Math.Pow(t, 3) + p3.X; should have been Math.Pow(t, 3) * p3.X;. Now it works.